# Use Linky _blank in angular $filter

Tags: angularjs

I am using linky to create the link from text with a valid URL. 
Using ng-bind-html="string  | linky:'_blank'"  was breaking the HTML rendering. So I created a custom filter, so that issue is solved. No, i have the Link and the proper body. But now the URL is opening in the same Tab. How do I apply the _blank attribute to linky?

```
My code:

    <span ng-bind-html="to_trusted(body | linkyWithHtml)"></span>


    app.filter('linkyWithHtml', function($filter) {
  return function(value) {
    if(value){
      var linked = $filter('linky')(value.toString());
      var replaced = linked.replace(/\&gt;/g, '>').replace(/\&lt;/g, '<');
      return replaced;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: can you do `var replaced = linked.replace(/\&gt;/g, ' target="_blank" >').replace(/\&lt;/g, '<');` so that the link will open in a new tab?

Comment: sure let me try

Comment: So this converted all the <br> to <br target="_blank" >, but the <a></a> tags did not change

Comment: I have never used linky so cant help much, can we replace all the a tags to target="_blank", like so     `var replaced = linked.replace(/\&gt;/g, '>').replace(/\&lt;/g, '<').replace("<a", "<a target='_blank'")`

Comment: @NarenMurali that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
So finally I got the solution 


app.filter('linkyWithHtml', function($filter) {
  return function(value) {
    if(value){
      var linked = $filter('linky')(value.toString());
      var replaced = linked.replace(/\&gt;/g, '>').replace(/\&lt;/g, '<').replace("<a", "<a target='_blank'")
      return replaced;
    } else{
      return value;
    }
  };
});
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5924562/naren-murali

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to use the "target" argument of the `linky` filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky#overview

```
app.filter('linkyWithHtml', function($filter) {
  return function(value) {
    if(value){
      var linked = $filter('linky')(value.toString(), '_blank');
      return linked;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  };
});
```